# Rounding (flooring) numbers to asymmetric resolution

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, rounding

I am building a variable resolution ruler control for a data visualization program. I want it to show axes tick labels depending on zoom level.

For exemple, with a very wide zoom, it would plot only [100, 200, 300] tick labels. Then if I close zoom, it would show, say, [10, 15, 20, 25] labels.

The numbers would always be multiple of 5 or 10. So, a partial "rounding grid" would be [1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000], but that would grow infinitely for both sides (including decimal numbers.

The question is: given an arbitrary positive floating point number, how could I 'floor' it to the first smaller number in the grid?

(This would allow me to set the granularity of the tick labels according to the plotter's zoom level/scale).

Mind that:

- The grid is "infinite" (that's why I didn't use sorting and other list methods);
- There is no fixed set of values to the floating point number, except it's always positive and non-zero.
- (EDIT) The resolution IS NOT SYMMETRIC, the tick intervals are, say, [1,5,10,50,100,500,...], the increment multipliers being, alternately, 2 and 5!

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the most significant digit is<5, use 1 and (k-1) zeros where k is the length of the number, else use 1 and (k-1) zeros. The following function works.

```
import numpy as np
def truncate(x):
    length = 0
    if x>=1:
        while x>=10:
            length+=1
            x/=10
    else:
        while x<1:
            length-=1
            x*=10
    r = max(0,-length) 
    if x<5:
        return round(np.power(10.0,length),r)
    else:
        return round(5*np.power(10.0,length),r)
```

Comment: I tried `truncate(320)` and it goes on looping forever... EDIT: I'm using Python, so `^` should be `**`. But even so, it gives a smaller grid than desired (50 instead of 100 for the number 320)

Comment: Where would you put the new line `x/=10` ?

Comment: @heltonbiker placement of x/=10, but I had changed indentation of the following code. I just tested it in python and it works.

Comment: Now it's fine for values above 1, but it should work for values in the interval (0,1].

Comment: @heltonbiker Now it should work for 0 < x < 1 also. Note that I am not handling cases where x <= 0.

Answer (score 0):

use modulo operator.
it is `%` in many languages  `^` means power

if tick is an integer, use:

```
newValue  =  value - value % tick
```

if tick is a float (or even an integer) use:

```
tickDecimals = decimalsOf(tick)      // pseudo function to know how much decimals tick has
newValue  =  (value * 10 ^ tickDecimals - ((value * 10 ^ tickDecimals) % (tick * 10 ^ tickDecimals))) / 10 ^ tickDecimals    // some parentheses are redundant
```

Comment: It should work for multiples of five, too, so [1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500,...]

Comment: this works for any value of tick. multiples of 5 or any other number